# Compiling project with NIFs with rebar: cl.exe not found

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm new to erlang and rebar. In my rebar project I used a dependency containing native c code and during `rebar compile` I'm getting error:

`Name cl.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I guess that rebar is trying to compile c files from my dependency using Microsoft's cl.exe compiler from VisualStudio, right? The problem is that I don't have VS installed and don't want to install it.

Why rebar is trying to use cl.exe? Can I configure rebar to use different compiler to compile c files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments in the [rebar port compiler](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_port_compiler.erl#L46) code, you can provide an alternative C compiler by adding something like this to your `rebar.config`:

```
{port_env, [{"CC", "/path/to/gcc.exe"}]}.
```

You will most likely have to change the `CFLAGS` to match the compiler. To compile NIFs and ports the OTP headers and development libraries must be compiled and available.