# Compiling NIF project with rebar on Windows

Tags: c, erlang, erl

In order to run my first NIF project on Windows i followed these steps:

1. Download Hellonif -master :https://github.com/vmx/hellonif
2. open command prompt(cmd):

   2.1 cd  C:\Users\Desktop\hellonif-master           =>project path

   2.2 SET PATH=C:\Program Files\C:\Program Files\erl6.4\bin => escript path
3. added this line to rebar.config: {port_env, [{"CC", "/C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin/mingw32-gcc"}]}.
4. open command prompt(cmd)

   4.1 rebar compile

Unfortunately I had this error :

```
hellonif-master (compile)
compiling C:\Users\Desktop\hellonif-master\c_src\hello.c
La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte.
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please unlocalize error message?

Comment: sorry for using french this is the translation of error message:The syntax of the file name, directory or volume is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CC` path is invalid. Standard windows file path notation is

```
 "Drive:\dir\dir\file".
```

Also windows accepts straight slash on the command line level, that gives you

```
"Drive:/dir/dir/file".
```

Some ported Linux applications require mingw or cygwin path format:

```
Mingw: "/drive/dir/dir/file"
Cygwin "/cygdrives/drive/dir/dir/file"
```

Your `"/Drive:/dir/dir/file"` is not valid.

However, you can just add your CC path to your search path list (`PATH`), and use standard `cc` or `gcc` file name for compiler (Mingw provides both applications as references to `mingw32-gcc`)

Comment: Thank you Lol4t0 for your answer ,I don't undrestand the first solution what   is the path that i should put in my case .for the second solution i added C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin to the PATH but i have this error:"cl.exe is not recognized" .thanks in advance

Comment: try `"C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin/gcc.exe"` or `"/C/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin/gcc.exe"`. For second it want `cl` (that is MSVC compiler) unfortunately, for second you can try additionaly set `CC=gcc`.

Comment: I tried "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin/gcc.exe" and "/C/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin/gcc.exe" but still not working i read in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043040/compiling-project-with-nifs-with-rebar-cl-exe-not-found that i should change CFLAGS is it mandatory to change this variable ?? if so how to change this variable (i don't have Makefile in my project)and what's the value of this variable

Comment: You don't have to change CFLAGS if you don't want. CFLAGS are just compiler flags

Comment: when i choose the compiler as i did here, how the compiler recognize the header files erl_nif.h... isn't that the probem???